# Pass through request to PHP FPM socket

Tags: sockets, unix, php

I set up **nginx** with **PHP-FPM**. The (still) simple PHP script should "pass on" the request to an PHP-FPM unix socket for now. From what I have read so far, [PHP's socket](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php) extension is suitable for the base. I just do not have any clue what to do with such a socket. I guess I need to implement the whole "server side" of FastCGI, do I?

Background: There is a web app. That web app only deals with log in and out of users. If a user is logged in, requests are passed through to other web apps on the same machine. Those other web apps are accessible only through a PHP FPM socket. The reason for running each in its own pool is to jail (chroot) each web app in a specific directory. Thinking about inversion of control, the web apps get necessary resources (in example user identity or database) provided by the proxy app or framework (did not work on that inter-app communication part yet).
**In general: In some way I try to mimic the sandboxing from apps on desktop and mobile operating systems for web apps.** Or better said: try to find a way how to.
If you think that is an awful idea, please tell me, since I am working on a proof-of-concept anyway.

Comment: Okay. This sounds like an awful idea. You're looking at a lot of work re-implementing FCGI, in a language that's not really suitable for it. If you needed to do this, C would be a much better language for something like this. But if it's just authentication, couldn't you use `auto_prepend_file`? See http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file

Comment: I would rather add another host in nginx, that is only reachable from localhost. This would have another doc-root and so on. Then your app could call this other app by http (rest?!)

Comment: @JeremiahWinsley It's ugly and only temporary, just to check if it works at all. Auto prepending stuff is not possible, since the authentication code needs more and different privileges regarding file system and database access than the sanboxed web app.

Comment: @MichaelFreund: I was considering it for a moment to run each web app on its own port. It would dramatically simplify the whole thing. Inter app commmunication via REST API and authorization by OAuth (something that way, just usual technologies but on same host).